# Counting the ways for two professors to schedule individual exams for $12$ students

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Two professors are scheduling separate individual exams for $12$ students in the same hour. Examination of one student in each subject takes $5$ minutes. In how many ways can this scheduling be made?

My answer to this question is $12!$. However, I think it's not right.

We have $12$ slots. $60$ minutes divided by $5$ minutes = $12$ slots. 
So,

- $12$ choices for the first student
- $11$ for the second
- $10$ for the third
- etc.

Multiplying it out: $12\cdot 11 \cdot 10\cdot 9 \dots = 479001600$

Answer (score 1):

$12!$ is correct for the number of orders for the exams given by the first professor.  But now we have to consider the second professor.  I assume we are to avoid conflicts, so the same student does not take both exams at the same time.  In that case you need a [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the students-a permutation with no fixed points.  That will take every student to a different time.

Comment: How to apply the derangement formula

Comment: Each arrangement for the first prof gives $!12$ arrangements for the second, so multiply them.